# Multithreading in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

Hey all
I have a problem with multithreading in java. This is my scenario. I have a class,which name is LocalTime. This class should catch the current time of system, and via a method,which name is getCurrentTime, return this value to a Form. This is the code of this class

```
public class LocalTime implements Runnable {

 private String currentTime=null;
 Thread t;
 private long time;
 private long h;
 private long m;
 private long s;
 public LocalTime() {
    t=new Thread(this,"current Time");
    t.start();

 }

 public synchronized void run() {

    try {
        for(;;){
        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    time = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
                    h = (time / 3600) % 24;
                    m = (time / 60) % 60;
                    s = time % 60;
                    this.currentTime=h+":"+m+":"+s;
        }
     } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(LocalTime.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
     }

 }
 public String getCurrentTime(){
     return  this.currentTime;
 }

}
```

and this is the code of main form:

```
public MainForm1() {
    initComponents();
    LocalTime l=new LocalTime();
    this.jLabel1.setText(l.getCurrentTime());//show the current time
    //The rest of code
}
```

now my major problem is the *jLabel1* text which shows current system time does not update each 1 second. If I insert *for(;;)* before the line of *jLabel1.setText(l.getCurrentTime())* the rest of code won't be reacheable. what should I to correct this error? please suggest me solution with these assumptions. I know that I can run a thread in *MainForm1*, too but I want some solution to this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183318/improve-accuracy-of-my-timer-thread

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you just read the time once. You should either start a worker thread that queries `LocalTime` or add a listener to `LocalTime` that is informed of time changes and triggers the label update.

As a side note: you might want to use `new Date()` in conjunction with a  `SimpleDateFormat` in order to get a nicely formatted representation.

Comment: Just a note that you shouldn't be calling `setText` from a worker thread.  So since you need to queue the update back on the event thread anyway, it's much easier just to use a Swing timer as Rom1 suggests.

Answer (score 2):

Please, please use a [Timer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) for that kind of task... Why go to all that extra complexity?
Try something like this:

```
  int delay = 1000; //milliseconds
  ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
     final LocalTime locTime = new LocalTime();
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
         jLabel1.setText(locTime.getCurrentTime());
     }
  };
  new Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start();
```

Comment: I updated the link to a more recent Javadoc, 1.4 is years out of date.  Do you think you could expand on how to use a Swing timer here, given the OP is probably new to Swing?

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are not including crucial pieces of code, there is no way for the label to be updated more than once.

See, your custom thread is kicking every second, updating it's own `this.currentTime` field.

But your label (at least with the meager amount of code that you are showing), it only gets updated once (via `this.jLabel1.setText(l.getCurrentTime())`) with whatever `l` had in it's time field **at that moment**.

Just because the local time thread runs, that doesn't mean it will magically go out and update the label. Why would it magically do it if you don't code that yourself? Think about it.

What you need to do is to have the thread update the label itself within it's run method. Moreover, this should be done within the Swing thread rules (and in the event queue) How you refactor that so that you get clean code, that's a topic for another thread.

```
// java pseudocode

public void run() {

    Runnable labelUpdater = new Runnable()
    {
      public void run()
      {
        someForm.jLabel1.setText(yourUpdatedTimeFormattedAsStringOrWhatever);
      }
    }
    try {
        for(;;){
           Thread.sleep(1000);
           // will cause label update to occur in the awt event queue
           SwingUtils.invokeLater(labelUpdater); 
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(LocalTime.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

Some notes:

1. You don't need the `synchronized` keyword in this specific instance of your run() method.
2. Use java.util.Calendar and java.util.Format to get string representations of the current time. What you are doing there with all that string concatenation and dividing the output of System.currentTimeMillis() is just bad. Have you looked at the Java API to see what's already there for you????????

Stuff for you to read:

Concurrency in Swing
http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/threads/threads1.html#event_dispatching

Concurrency (the Java Tutorial)
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

Answer (score 0):

Create a [TimerTask](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html) and call the **setText** in timer's run method. Then [schedule](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long%29) the task to be executed every second.

Comment: `setText` needs to be called from the EDT.  A Swing timer is a better choice.

Comment: @Mark Peters - Exactly. The OP needs to dispatch the update on the event queue. This very clearly explained in the Sun (now Oracle) site : http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/threads/threads1.html

Comment: Yes that would be better solution. I never worked on swing so did not know about Swing timer. Thanks for comments. I just looked at the way thread.sleep() was used inside a loop so tried to correct the approach.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one thing that u are misssing is to update the label after each second. the thread which is calculating the time by using system date is working fine. What u can do is raise an event after each second and change the value of textfield in the listener of the event.